# How to make facebook chatbot public without Business verification for freelancers?

Tags: facebook, chatbot

I am creating chat bot for facebook , my bot just answer me I think because this is not submitted for review yet , is it true ?

I made it in public mode but nothing changed!

so I asked review for the app but facebook needs Business verification that I don’t have because I’m just freelancer

so what can I do to make it public?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

As facebook is fighting to gain their image back after being involved in some major data breaches recently, they are asking Chatbot developers to connect their Bots to real businesses.

The business verification process will take time from weeks to months, requiring appropriated documents proving the page business is real!

I see, therefore, there's no chance to publish your bot now, or even in the future, without having any serious business for the page! You, as developer of this Bot, can still have response from the Bot. Others, who want to connect with your Bot, must be gained a Role like Tester...

Comment: so there is no chanse ! because we cant make any people tester !!

Comment: I think yess :)

Comment: that's so bad... fb should accept at least personal documents, for personal pages